# MYSQL clause IN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

https://api.genmymodel.com/projects/_Fiqh0AYoEeaCaNzs6cfLZA/diagrams/_Fiqh0gYoEeaCaNzs6cfLZA/jpeg

I have one or more keywords and I want to find all doctor who are associate to all of them.
How to do that in Mysql.

I try :

```
SELECT *
FROM Doctor, DoctorKeyword, Keyword 
WHERE DoctorKeyword.idKeyword IN (SELECT id 
                                  FROM Keyword 
                                  WHERE word = "test" 
                                  OR word = "anotherTest") 
AND DoctorKeyword.idDoctor = Doctor.id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DoctorKeyword.idKeyword)= 2
```

I want to find all doctors who have all keywords in the IN clause

```
Exemple of table Doctor

    id|name    |address
    1 | John   | los Angeles
    2 | Patrick| Miami
    3 | Michal | Miami

Exemple of table Keyword

    id|word
    1 | test
    2 | anotherTest
    3 | merc

Exemple of table DoctorKeyword

    id|idDoctor|idKeyword
    1 | 1      | 1
    2 | 1      | 2
    3 | 2      | 3
    4 | 2      | 1
    5 | 2      | 2
```

Comment: Can you please share your table design and some sample data

Comment: The table design is in the first link

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and not rely on external resources that may become unavailable in the future.

Comment: Any other solution ?

Comment: Is `DoctorKeyword (idDoctor, idKeyword)` a unique key?

Comment: Not in the structure of database but logically yes

Comment: Another solution ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct doctor.* /* select distinct list of doctors from Doctor */
from #Doctor doctor, #Keyword keyword, #DoctorKeyword dk
where doctor.id = dk.idDoctor /* Inner join Doctor on DoctorKeyword */
and keyword.id = dk.idKeyword /* Inner join Keyword on DoctorKeyword */
and keyword.word in ('test','anotherTest') /* Using only values in which the word is 'test' or 'anotherTest' in Keyword*/
```

Working POC:

```
begin
create table #Doctor (id int, name varchar(10), address varchar(20))
create table #Keyword (id int, word varchar(10))
create table #DoctorKeyword (id int, idDoctor int, idKeyword int)

insert into #Doctor(id, name,address) values (1,'John', 'los Angeles')
insert into #Doctor(id, name,address) values (2,'Patrick', 'Miami')
insert into #Doctor(id, name,address) values (3,'Michal', 'Miami')
insert into #Keyword (id,word) values (1,'test')
insert into #Keyword (id,word) values (2,'anotherTest')
insert into #Keyword (id,word) values (3,'merc')
insert into #DoctorKeyword(id,idDoctor,idKeyword) values(1,1,1)
insert into #DoctorKeyword(id,idDoctor,idKeyword) values(2,1,2)
insert into #DoctorKeyword(id,idDoctor,idKeyword) values(3,2,3)
insert into #DoctorKeyword(id,idDoctor,idKeyword) values(4,2,1)
insert into #DoctorKeyword(id,idDoctor,idKeyword) values(5,2,2)

select distinct doctor.*
from #Doctor doctor, #Keyword keyword, #DoctorKeyword dk
where doctor.id = dk.idDoctor 
and keyword.id = dk.idKeyword 
and keyword.word in ('test','anotherTest') 

end
```

Result 
id | name    | address 
1  | John    | los Angeles 
2  | Patrick | Miami

Comment: This doesn't not a solution

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: Is that better? @Aziz

Answer (score 0):

try this and tell me if not works

```
   SELECT k.id,dk.id,d.id,d.name  FROM Keyword as k join DoctorKeyword as dk      on
k.id=dk.idKeyword 
join doctor as d on dk.idDoctor=d.id
                              WHERE k.word = "test" 
                              OR k.word = "anotherTest"
```

Comment: I try this, but this return me all doctor who have test or anotherTest and not doctor who have both off them only

Comment: Ive edit check now and tell me i dnt have server @user3469006

Comment: It's the same, it return me Doctor who are associate to test and doctor who are associate to anotherTest. But i want doctor associate to both only

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the server to test my query, can you please check below query

```
SELECT *
FROM Doctor
JOIN DoctorKeyword ON(Doctor.id = DoctorKeyword.idDoctor)
JOIN Keyword ON(Keyword.id = DoctorKeyword.idKeyword)
WHERE Keyword.word = 'test' 
OR Keyword.word='anotherTest'
HAVING COUNT(DoctorKeyword.idKeyword) = 2;
```

Comment: This don't return me anything

Answer (score 0):

```
I find the solution and i want to share it : 

SELECT * FROM Doctor 
WHERE id 
IN (SELECT idDoctor FROM DoctorKeyword INNER JOIN Keyword ON idKeyword = Keyword.id WHERE word = "test" 
AND id 
IN (SELECT idDoctor FROM DoctorKeyword INNER JOIN Keuword ON idKeyword = Keyword.id WHERE word = "anotherTest"
```